# Query for displaying related usernames that match a given username

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

What would the query be if lets say the person searches for a username --> johnny123 and if there is no such username, then i want it to return a list usernames that match the pattern of the username entered like johnny12345 , johnnyboy etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username like 'johnny%';
```

This will search all the username starting with "johnny".

Comment: Hey Paz, what if i want to make it case insensitive..?

Comment: Hey i figured that out, just preceeded the LIKE with an I and its done! What if i want to use the LIKE with a parameter that i passed in the method. My method has the username parameter, so I want to use the LIKE keyword against the value passed to that parameter rather than hardcoding the value. How do i go about doing that??

Comment: in which programming you are using this query?
You just have to use according to that language, like in .net i use
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username like @USERNAME
and passing the username with parameters in mysqlquery
Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Paz, im using the Npgsql data provider for postgresql in .net with C# , so would the postgresql query be the same as the sql one you posted in the above comment?

Comment: Hey never mind.. i figured out a way using the following query --> "select \"UserName\" from \"Users\" where \"UserName\" ILIKE :relatedUser"; and then using command.parameters.AddWithValue() method

Answer (score 1):

This will return a single match for johnny123. Otherwise, if no johnny123 is found, it will return everything that starts with 'johnny'. Not elegant, but it does what you described.

Using the function below, you would go `select * from username.test('username');`

```
create function username.test(text)
  returns setof text as $$
  declare
    usr text;
  begin
    usr := (select username from tablename where v like $1);
  if (usr is not null)
    then
       return next usr;     
  else
    return query (select username from tablename where v like '' || $1 || '%'); 
  end if;
  return;
  end;
  $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
select * from table_name
where username like '%johnny%';
```

This will return all the rows that have johnny in their username. For example, if your table contains these three usernames:

```
johnny123
123johnny
123johnny456
```

All the rows will be returned as they contain johnny in their username.